# Expose port in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

In minikube, how to expose a service using nodeport ?

For example, I start a kubernetes cluster using the following command and create and expose a port like this:

```
$ minikube start
$ kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080
$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
$ curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url)
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=192.168.99.1
command=GET
real path=/ ....
```

Now how to access the exposed service from the host? I guess the minikube node needs to be configured to expose this port as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "access the exposed service from the host"?  It seems that you are already able to access the hello-minikube service from the host at the url specified by:
`minikube service hello-minikube --url`

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually it was configuration error because of which the port was not accessible from the host and I was in a confusion that I need to change some firewall settings to make it accessible.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking as it seems you already know about the `minikube service <SERVICE_NAME> --url` command which will give you a url where you can access the service. In order to open the exposed service, the `minikube service <SERVICE_NAME>` command can be used:

```
$ kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080
deployment "hello-minikube" created
$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
service "hello-minikube" exposed
$ kubectl get svc
NAME             CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
hello-minikube   10.0.0.102   <nodes>       8080/TCP   7s
kubernetes       10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    13m

$ minikube service hello-minikube
Opening kubernetes service default/hello-minikube in default browser...
```

This command will open the specified service in your default browser.

There is also a `--url` option for printing the url of the service which is what gets opened in the browser:

```
$ minikube service hello-minikube --url
http://192.168.99.100:31167
```

Comment: On my Linux host it cannot find the port `$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
error: couldn't find port via --port flag or introspection`

Comment: You need to expose the port too @Stephane. Example:
`kubectl expose deployment influxdb --port=8086 --target-port=8086`

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to hit the exposed NodePort service (web-nodeport) on localhost:31000, but that didn't work. minikube service web-nodeport did worked. But curious why localhost didn't worked.

Comment: @MahtabAlam it does not work as the NodePort is exposed inside of a VM that minikube is running k8s in, not the host machine.  You can use the new `minikube tunnel` command which should proxy the ports to interact with localhost.

Comment: github url is broken.

Answer (score 52):

As minikube is exposing access via `nodeIP:nodePort` and not on `localhost:nodePort`, you can get this working by using `kubectl`'s port forwarding capability. For example, if you are running mongodb service:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/mongo 27017:27017
```

This would expose the service on `localhost:27017`, FWIW. Furthermore, you might want to figure out how to run this in background.

Comment: this is exactly what im looking for

Answer (score 34):

minikube runs on something like `192.168.99.100`. So you should be able to access it on the `NodePort` you exposed your service at. For eg, say your `NodePort` is `30080`, then your service will be accessible as `192.168.99.100:30080`.

To get the minikube ip, run the command `minikube ip`.

**Update Sep 14 2017:**

Here's a small example that works with minikube `v0.16.0`.

1) Run the commands below to create an nginx running on 8080 and a `NodePort` `svc` forwarding to it:

```bash
$ kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=8080
deployment "hello-minikube" created
$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
service "hello-minikube" exposed
```

2) Find the nodeport used by the svc:

```bash
$ kubectl get svc hello-minikube
NAME             CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello-minikube   10.0.0.76    <nodes>       8080:30341/TCP   4m
```

3) Find the minikube ip:

```bash
$ minikube ip
192.168.99.100
```

4) Talk to it with curl:

```bash
$ curl 192.168.99.100:30341
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=172.17.0.1
command=GET
real path=/
...
```

Comment: This does not appear to be true.

Comment: 1) kubernetes assigns an IP & port to the exposed service
2) that IP & port are running on a VM with a virtual IP that your laptop doesn't have native access to.

Comment: @macrael This is 100% true and works on windows, mac and Linux. Please check your VM network settings, your kubernetes settings or post them here so that others can help. The downvote is unwarranted!

Comment: @icordoba Just tested this on macos as well. Are you able to ping your minikube VM? Try reproducing the instructions?

Comment: can I define the exposed port? I mean, what do I have to do if I want to expose  it to 8080 (192.168.99.100:8080)

Comment: I have been at this all day. Minikube on mac does not setup an IP address you can hit via browser. Says and hasnt changed in over 2 hours. I have been reading mixed messages that loadBalancer works and does not work for minikube.

Anyone else get this to work yet? I had an instance running and working with Ambassador, but not without it yet.

Comment: `kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort` command from the example doesn't work for me (MacOS minikube + docker driver, minikube version: v1.14.0, docker engine version 19.03.13, k8s client 1.18, k8s server 1.19)

Comment: Worked great for me on Linux with minikube/vbox !!! This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @DmitryShvetsov It doesn't work for me too. 

Why we require minikube service command? Can we do without using it?

Comment: the deployment and service names end up being `helloworld`, not `hello-minicube`, when I run it.

Comment: @macrael - that is because the answer is incomplete. The above probably works in a specific kind of Minikube cluster - maybe vbox (since a network between the host and guests are created). The default Minikube cluster is that of docker and this answer does not work with it. Must either be added to the answer, failing which it is extremely misleading and, in a way, wrong!

Comment: how solve if write in yaml file?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar issue in 2022. Here are the commands I ran:

1. `kubectl create deployment deploymentName --image=dockerHubUsername/imageTag:imageVersion`
2. `kubectl expose deployment deploymentName --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080`
3. `minikube tunnel`
4. `kubectl get services deploymentName` this provides the external ip address needed to access the application. I access the app with `127.0.0.1:8080`

[Source](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/)

Comment: For future reference, this worked on a Mac M1.

Comment: For the scenario where `--type=NodePort`, there's no external IP address. How does this then work?

Answer (score 4):

Just a note for anyone looking for connection refused answers: If your minikube does not run on "something like 192.168.99.100" you probably runned with another vm-driver like "none". In that case delete your minikube cluster and rebuild using the default. it 'll work....ish... I do not seem to be able to get the tunnel working...

Comment: Thanks this resolved my issue. I started the minikube cluster without vm-driver option. Deleted the minikube cluster and used minikube start driver=hyperkit on MacOS resolved the issue. Remember for macos users, you can use any of the drivers listed here https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/

Answer (score 1):

I'm using wsl2 on windows11 docker desktop. the only thing that worked for me was using service type ClusterIp, together with the command:
 `kubectl port-forward svc/<service name> -n <namespace> <host port>:<service port>`

I tried NodePort in any way, restarting minikube with the "--port" arg, but nothing else worked.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and struggle, this is what I found.

Minikube by default, uses docker as its VM Driver and due to that, whenever you start a minikube cluster, it creates a new network with the name minikube (you can find it using `docker network ls`. Hence, that minikune IP is only defined in that 'minikube' network.

To run minikube on the host network and give minikube IP as hostIP, you need to run minikube with `--vm-driver=none`

Below are the complete commands

```
# Make sure that version of minikube is v1.30.1
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v1.30.1/minikube-linux-amd64
sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube

# Make sure that version of kubectl is v1.23.0
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.23.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.service-node-port-range=300-20000 --memory=6g minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.23.0 --vm-driver=none
```

Minikube will expose via `nodeIP:nodePort` and not on `localhost:nodePort` when you use default vm-driver. If you use --vm-driver as none, it then uses `localhost`.