# Access minikube dashboard from another machine

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have installed minikube and launched it on the one of my machines.
IP is 192.168.4.122

And, minikube master launched successfully on 192.168.99.100
I can access minikube dashboard with this address: http://192.168.99.100:30000

But, I want to access the dashboard from another machine on the same subnet.(For example, 192.168.4.120 or 192.168.4.251)
How can I access the dashboard from another machine on the same LAN?

Comment: one way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173463/how-to-access-local-kubernetes-minikube-dashboard-remotely?rq=1