# minikube expose service on specific port

Tags: minikube

Is it possible to expose a service on a specific port using `minikube`?

`kubectl expose deployment my-deployment --type=NodePort --port=80` does not throw an error but when calling

`minikube service my-deployment --url`

it results in something like:

`http://192.168.99.100:31512` and it is not available on port `80` but on port `31512` instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Valid ports for `minikube` of type `nodePort` by default are `30000-32767` according to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

I was able to specify a particular port (here: `30000` in that range using this `services.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-deployment 
  labels:
    app: my-deployment 
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-deployment
```

When starting `minikube` this way:

`minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.service-node-port-range=80-30000`, port `80` can be used as well:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-deployment 
  labels:
    app: my-deployment 
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-deployment
```

`minikube service my-deployment --url` now returns `http://192.168.99.100:80` as expected and the application is available on port `80`.

Comment: what if I want to change that range for the node ports outside of minikube? I'm trying this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/ , changing the port, but even after restarting the kubelet service, nothing changes

Comment: I'm pretty sure I followed this and it's not working.  That is, it keeps giving me a random port and not the one specified in 'nodePort'.  Is it possible something has changed with this?

Comment: This answer solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55110218/1708543