# minikube service --url when service exposes multiple ports

Tags: portforwarding, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-service

My `my-app` service exposes multiple ports:

```
/Mugen$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME           ENDPOINTS                                                   AGE
my-app         172.17.0.7:80,172.17.0.7:8003,172.17.0.7:8001 + 3 more...   7m
kubernetes     192.168.99.100:8443                                         10h
mysql-server   172.17.0.5:3306                                             10h
```

When executing `minikube service my-app -n default --url`, I'm getting each port forwarded by minikube, however I can't tell which is which without querying them. Is there a simple way to print the mapping or to set the port forwarding myself?

```
/Mugen$ minikube service my-app -n default --url
http://192.168.99.100:30426
http://192.168.99.100:30467
http://192.168.99.100:31922
http://192.168.99.100:32008
http://192.168.99.100:30895
http://192.168.99.100:31602
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily check the port and TargetPort mapping in kubernetes service using:

```
kubectl descrive svc my-app
Name:                     my-app
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=MyApp
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.152.183.56
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               9376/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30696/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               9377/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32715/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

This way you can find `port`, `targetport` and `endpoints` mapping.

Comment: what I was missing besides that was setting `NodePort` to be same as `Port` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272296/minikube-expose-service-on-specific-port - Thanks!