# How to access NodePort in Minikube with docker driver?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos, minikube, spinnaker

I launched minikube with the docker driver on a remote machine and I have used a nodePort service for a particular pod. I believe nodePort exposes the port on the minikube docker container. On doing minikube IP it gave me the IP of the docker container in which minikube runs. How can I port map the port from the minnikube container to the host port so that I can access it remotely. A different approach would other than using driver=none or restarting minikube is appreciated as I do not want to restart my spinnaker cluster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a  `minikube service <SERVICE_NAME> --url` command which will give you a url where you can access the service. In order to open the exposed service, the `minikube service <SERVICE_NAME>` command can be used:

```
$ minikube service example-minikube
Opening kubernetes service default/hello-minikube in default browser...
```

This command will open the specified service in your default browser.

There is also a `--url` option for printing the url of the service which is what gets opened in the browser:

```
$ minikube service example-minikube --url
http://192.168.99.100:31167
```

You can run `minikube service list` to get list of all available services with their corresponding URL's. Also make sure the service points to correct pod by using correct `selector`.

Try also to execute command:

```
ssh -i ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L *:30000:0.0.0.0:30000
```

Take a look: [minikube-service-port-forward](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/877), [expose-port-minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767164/expose-port-in-minikube/40774861#40774861), [minikube-service-documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/minikube_service.md).

Comment: Hey, Thank you for replying. I tried doing this, As I said, the IP I get is of the docker container of MiniKube running on Bridge network. Hence, I cannot access it remotely.

Comment: By using the expose port method, it is possible for me to access the service on the machine on which minikube is running in docker container. However, the host machine is a headless CentOS server, which I am using remotely.

Comment: Have you tried to port forward a service https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/877 ? Try to execute command ssh -i ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L \*:30000:0.0.0.0:30000

Comment: Hey yes, this was the exact issue I was facing. This link was for when the driver is VM which has NAT support to port-forward at runtime. However, docker doesn't have anything as such. The other port forwarding methods worked.

Comment: Why would I want to execute that last command/What is the purpose of the the last command (the ssh command)?