# How to access `docker-compose` containers, in Minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, virtualbox, minikube

## Issue:

I want my web-server to have either a Kubernetes config **and** a Docker-Compose config.

I run them on a MacBook (no native containers support), so at the moment I

- run `docker-compose` on Docker Desktop
- run `kubectl` on a Minikube VM
  *(I stick to Minikube because of the convenient commands like `minikube ip` & `minikube service`, that I rely on in my scripts)*

This makes slow and inconvenient to switch from one setup to the other (suspend Minikube, start Docker Desktop, rebuild the images, re-run the services; and vice-versa).
They won't share built images or containers, and they run in different environments.

---

## Attempt

I tried running `docker-compose` on Docker from the Minikube VM.
Works fine, but **I cannot connect to the service**, because there is **no tunnelling or port-forwarding from the Host machine to the Minikube machine**
(while `compose` takes care of the inner forwarding from `$(minikube ip):8081` to `docker-container-webserver:8080`.

## Question

###### *How to open the connection from the Host machine (browser) to the container (web-server), that was run from `docker-compose` using the Docker provided by Minikube?*

I tried `minikube tunnel` but it didn't seem to help (it is designed to work with Kubernetes LoadBalancer services).

## UPDATE:

There was an official repository from Docker, with the steps to run Compose into Minikube, at https://github.com/docker/compose-on-kubernetes/blob/master/docs/install-on-minikube.md but unfortunately it is not maintained anymore, and each of those described steps cause errors.
However that shows that accessing Compose on Minikube is not trivial as simply tunneling/port-forwarding.
A pity...

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: It's `v1.20.7`; but it shouldn't matter. The issue is about `docker-compose` over Minikube, regardless of the cluster.

Comment: Are you sure that properly ports are open? Did you see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767164/expose-port-in-minikube)?

Comment: Nope sorry, I had to go on with the project and Minikube stopped working on Virtualbox (simply doing `minikube delete && minikube start`); doesn't even provision the VM anymore ‍♂️. I'm fed up with Minikube; it wasted more time than it saved since I started using it; too many hard to diagnose problems and instability; imho one additional layer too much. Maybe there's no way to reach *docker-compose* services, because the VM is focused on running Kubernetes (`minikube tunnel`, `ingress-dns`, port-forwarding). I gave up and am now running either Compose and K8s Cluster via Docker Desktop.

Comment: Use an [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Comment: An ingress on `docker-compose`? I thought it is a concept exclusive to Kubernetes, not related to Docker.

Answer (score -1):

You can expose the service as "NodePort".
e.g

```
kubectl expose deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME --type=NodePort --target-port=PORT --NAME=SERVICE_NAME
```

Then you can access the service using minikube node IP. Use the following to generate the accessible URL of the service.

```
minikube service SERVICE_NAME --url
```

Comment: Do you mean a Kubernetes `DEPLOYMENT_NAME`? My issue is with `docker-compose`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: yes, it is deployment of Kubernetes, that runs in Minikube. You question was "How to open the connection from the Host machine (browser) to the container (web-server) running inside Minikube?" So, once the service is exposed as NodePort, it is accessible over the Minikube node IP from the host machine.

Comment: Ok, but I _do not_ want to access a K8s deployment, I want access to the Docker daemon. The question description is _not_ about accessing a K8s deployment's service, but only about connecting to Docker provided by Minikube's VM.