# How to expose a service from minikube to be able to access it from another device in the same network?

Tags: docker, express, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I've created a service inside minikube (expressjs API) running on my local machine,
so when I launch the service using   `minikube service wedeliverapi --url`    I can access it from my browser with   `localhost:port/api`

[image]

[image]

But I also want to access that service from another device so I can use my API from a flutter mobile application. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expose port in minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767164/expose-port-in-minikube)

Comment: No brother I don't know if I explained what I want well but as the first image provided shows that I can access my service throw my browser but the thing is that I want to access it from another machine in the same network !

Comment: Which [driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) do you use? Do you use MacOS or Linux..?

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for https://ngrok.com/.

Comment: maybe I don't know ! but sounds amazing tool I'll give it a try

Comment: Hello @WrakAli, any updates here?

Comment: hi @kkopczak the solution I fund is to install a reverse proxy using Nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to small amount of information and to clarify everything- I am posting a general Community wiki answer.

The solution to solve this problem was to use **reverse proxy server**. In [this documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/) is definiton what exactly is **reverse proxy server** .

> A proxy server is a go‑between or intermediary server that forwards requests for content from multiple clients to different servers across the Internet. A **reverse proxy server** is a type of proxy server that typically sits behind the firewall in a private network and directs client requests to the appropriate backend server. A reverse proxy provides an additional level of abstraction and control to ensure the smooth flow of network traffic between clients and servers

Common uses for a [reverse proxy server](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) include:

- Load balancing
- Web acceleration
- Security and anonymity

[This](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) is the guide where one can find basic configuration of a proxy server.

See also [this article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/nginx-reverse-proxy).