# How to setup a nginx reverse proxy for a minikube service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, minikube

I have a minikube service running on `http://192.168.49.2:31746` on the server with IP address `10.128.135.6`

[image]

When I `curl http://192.168.49.2:31746` on the server on which Minikube is running, I can access the service. However, I want to access this service on the local network from clients also(within the local network).

I have found that I will need to set up Nginx reverse proxy for this but I am not able to get it working.
Here are the steps I followed to run nginx on docker

1. Made a Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 8765
```

2. Made a nginx.conf file in the same directory with contents

```
server {
    listen 8765;
    server_name 10.128.135.6;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.49.2:31746;
    }
}
```

3. Built the docker image using

```
docker build -t my-nginx .
```

4. Run the docker container.

```
docker run -p 8765:8765 -d my-nginx
```

what I want is when I go to the URL `http://10.128.135.6:8765/hub/login` on a system in the local network, the request should go to `http://192.168.49.2:31746/hub/login`

Comment: Refer to [How to Deploy NGINX Reverse Proxy on Docker](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-nginx-reverse-proxy), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Also refer to similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767164/expose-port-in-minikube).