# Can not access the application through the nodePort

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using minikube to test my application locally before deploying it to GKE.

However, I still can not access my application through the nodeport despite specifying the appropriate ports and aligning all the labels between the service and deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi-deployment
  labels:
    app: fastapi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fastapi
        image: jrpespinas/ml-engine-sample:1.1.3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fastapi-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: fastapi
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 30700
```

Using the following command, this was the output.

```
$ minikube service fastapi-service    
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |      NAME       | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | fastapi-service |        8080 | http://192.*.*.*:30700 |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|---------------------------|
```

I used asterisk to mask the actual url.

I have been trying out the previous stackoverflow answers but unfortunately nothing works.

Comment: [Expose port in minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767164/expose-port-in-minikube) has quite a bit of discussion of this; is this question different from what's asked there?

Comment: Gave it a look. I can access it through the local IP given, but I need to access it through the <minikube ip>:<nodePort>

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below troubleshooting steps in order to overcome the issue:

1. Check your firewall rules if the port is blocked, you can check it by using telnet command with minikube ip and port number 30700.
2. Try [port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) using below command:

   `kubectl port-forward service {serviceName} -n {namespaceName} {portNumberToAccess}:{portNumberOfService}.`
3. Try the resolution steps mentioned by harlesbayu in this [git issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7344#issuecomment-703225254).

> ```
> a) Install virtualbox
>
> b) Start minikube => minikube start --driver=virtualbox
>
> c) Check ip minikube: minikube ip
> ```

For more information  refer to this [document](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/).

Answer (score 0):

try to run `minikube tunnel`

[tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/)

**edit:** 
minikube simulates a cluster on your host
so you have a port in the container, a port in the cluster, and a port for your host system to talk to the cluster. 
on Windows 10 using docker as driver for minikube 
I needed to use a tunnel for crate tunnel between minikube VM and my host. 
so my new address was something like:  http://127.0.0.1:59759 
and all the traffic forwarded to the Kubernetes cluster via that tunnel

Comment: Please improve your answer by posting why you are suggesting this