# Kubernetes NodePort on Minikube not accessible from outside

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-nodeport

my current service file:

```
spec:
  selector:
    name: some-pod
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8200
    targetPort: 8200
    nodePort: 30082
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.183.128
```

current deployment of a pod within the deployment:

```
template:
metadata:
  name: some-pod
  labels:
    name: some-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: container
        image: someimage
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add: ["CHOWN", "IPC_LOCK"]
        terminationMessagePath: "/tmp/pod-log"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8200
```

when I get the minikube url I get the following:

```
[root@kind vault]# minikube service some-service --url
http://192.168.49.2:30082
```

after googling and reading bunch of article I still could not figure out what was going on. Then I realized that the IP that minikube showed above was the minikube container's IP. This means that the "nodePort" defined in the service-yaml file was to the container not to the node itself.

I verified it too by the following:

```
I listed all the interface by "ip a"
my node's interface ens160: 192.168.183.128
container "br-6981f04e576e": ip address - 192.168.49.2
```

from the node I ran the port connectivity to the minikube container -- works as expected:

```
[root@kind vault]# nc -zvw10 192.168.49.2 30082
Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 192.168.49.2:30082.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.02 seconds.
```

I also tried putting the externalIPs in the **service** yaml file and that still did not work. 
then I looked into how to map the minikube "Running" container's port to the node's port and tired bunch such as **"docker commit"** and still nothing that helped! so please help!!

PS: I did allow the port 30082 port on the node itself and tested connectivity btw.

Comment: Have you checked this document on [Accessing apps](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) .This document states, "Services of type `LoadBalancer` can be exposed via the `minikube tunnel` command. It must be run in a separate terminal window to keep the LoadBalancer running. Ctrl-C in the terminal can be used to terminate the process at which time the network routes will be cleaned up".

Comment: @FariyaRahmat The service type is the LoadBalancer, however I am trying to make it work with the type "NodePort". I could try to the LoadBalancer as well but NodePort is what best fits for the project that I am working with!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it but not sure if this is the proper answer - which is by doing

```
kubectl port-forward svc/some-service 8200:8200
```

although this works, I still don't understand why the NodePort does not automatically do this by default as my understanding was the point of **service NodePort**.

Also another confusion:

- per my service file, the NodePort that was exposed was 30082 however, when I do kubectl port-forward I have to use **8200**, which is mapping my localhost directly to the pod so definitely don't see the point of NodePort service here.

Answer (score 0):

Minikube supports either load balancer or node port

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/):

> Services of type NodePort can be exposed via the minikube service
>  --url command. It must be run in a separate terminal
> window to keep the tunnel open. Ctrl-C in the terminal can be used to
> terminate the process at which time the network routes will be cleaned
> up.
>
> 1. Create a Kubernetes deployment
>
>    ```
>    kubectl create deployment hello-minikube1 --image=kicbase/echo-server:1.0
>    ```
> 2. Create a Kubernetes service type NodePort
>
>    ```
>    kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube1 --type=NodePort -- port=8080
>    ```
> 3. Check Node Port
>
>    ```
>    $ kubectl get svc
>     NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
>     hello-minikube1   NodePort    10.100.238.34   <none>        8080:31389/TCP   3s
>    ```
> 4. Run service tunnel
>
>    ```
>    minikube service hello-minikube1 --url
>    ```
>
>    `minikube service hello-minikube1 --url` runs as a process, creating
>    a tunnel to the cluster. The command exposes the service directly to
>    any program running on the host operating system.
> 5. Try in your browser
>
>    Open in your browser (ensure there is no proxy set)
>
>    ```
>    http://127.0.0.1:TUNNEL_PORT
>    ```

Comment: You can also refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767164/expose-port-in-minikube) which may help you to resolve your issue