# I can't access applications running in NodePort mode in the K8S Minikube Cluser

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

- Im running a python application in Minikube Cluster.
- I created a K8S service in NodePort mode but can't able to access it through the browser.
- Can't make connection with the Minikube Cluster.
- I'll add the erros pics, please refer those.
- [Here is the Code Link](https://github.com/VishwaS-22/Kubernetes-Deployment/tree/main/UsingService/python-web-app).
- As per the rules, I gave the same Selector name in deployment.yml file as well as in Service.yml file but not able to access.
- But my application is running in Cluster IP,
- I don't want to use Load Balancer mode because can't use any Cloud.
- I tried for hours but can't solve it, without solving it I'm not able to move to learn about the Ingress.

Here is what I tried!

cat deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-python-app
  labels:
    app: sample-python-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-python-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-python-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: python-app
        image: vishwask22/python-sample-app-demo:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

$ cat service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-python-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: sample-python-app

  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 32000
```

$curl http://192.168.49.2:32000/demo -v

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
> Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
> --:--:--     0*   Trying 192.168.49.2:32000...   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--     0* connect to
> 192.168.49.2 port 32000 failed: Timed out
>
> - Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 32000 after 21036 ms: Couldn't connect to server   0     0    0     0    0     0      0
>   0 --:--:--  0:00:21 --:--:--     0
> - Closing connection 0 curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 32000 after 21036 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Comment: [Expose port in minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767164/expose-port-in-minikube) suggests using `minikube service sample-python-app` to access your application, rather than directly using the `minikube ip` and NodePort port.  Does that approach work for you?

Comment: I tried running the command "minikube service sample-python-app" but the URL it gives wont solved my problem. 

[1. http://192.168.49.2:30001 and 2. http://127.0.0.1:63381(Tunnel IP) ] both doesn't work, Throws site can't reached error.

Comment: Can you add container logs of your app? What is your OS?

Comment: Im using wnidows. Used git as my terminal and docker desktop will be running at the background.